# How to pass a constant outside of a viewmodel to a Knockout binding?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

Given that there is an enum and a viewmodel:

```
var MyEnum = {
   Val1 = 1,
   Val2 = 2
};

var someViewModel = {};
ko.applyBindings(someViewModel);
```

and a view:

```
<div data-bind="template: 'my-template', data: MyEnum.Val1"></div>
```

I can't find a way to pass the value of `MyEnum.Val1` to a binding, because Knockout looks for it inside the viewmodel. Prepending with `$root.MyEnum.Val1` doesn't work either, as it still looks within the viewmodel.

Any ideas how to get it working?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You can do it by passing the constant to the viewmodel during the initialization of the viewmodel

Comment: Do you mean making it a part of a viewmodel?

Comment: How about `var someViewModel = { MyEnum: MyEnum }` ?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to declare a viewModel as a function first instead of making them as object directly. By doing this we can reuse it in the future if needed and will have a neater process to pass the object to that viewModel during initialization.

Here is the example:

```
function someViewModel(enum) {
  this.myEnum = enum;
};

var MyEnum = {
  Val1: 1,
  Val2: 2
};

ko.applyBindings(new someViewModel(MyEnum));
```

Then in the HTML you can do the following

```
<div data-bind="template: 'my-template', data: myEnum.Val1"></div>
```